# How many Jellybeans are in the bottle

Tags: lateral-thinking, combinatorics

There are $n$ jellybeans in a bottle with unknown dimensions. What is the only surefire way of knowing how many jellybeans are in the bottle?

Comment: +1, an easy question, but still might be interesting to the beginners.

Comment: I've made a discussion about problem difficulty here:  http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/new-feature-suggestion

Comment: Maybe this is lateral thinking? I mean, the only reason this wouldn't be immediately answered (and thus not really a puzzle) is because people try to ignore trivial answers.

Comment: These types of questions attract the dumbness in my brain, hahah DVL16 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Perhaps by counting the number of jellybeans in the bottle.

Comment: Alternative Answer: Eat them and say 0!

Comment: Could you place this as a spoiler?

Comment: @warspyking eating them all means 0 are in the bottle, 0!=1 isn't zero :P

Comment: You'd better pour them out of the bottle first, otherwise you can only see the outer layer.

Answer (score 8):

> You can empty the bottle and count the jellybeans on the table.

Comment: Why even bother counting them? If they're no longer in the bottle, the bottle contains zero jellybeans.

Answer (score 5):

There is another way that is probably far less time-consuming, depending on $n$.

> Weigh the bottle of jellybeans. Call this value $F$.
>  Pour out the bottle of jellybeans.
>  Weigh the empty bottle. Call this value $E$.
>  Weigh a single jellybean. Call this value $J$.

The number of jellybeans is

> $\frac{F-E}{J}$.

Comment: You have no measure of the standard deviation of jelly bean mass this way. For a very large population, this will not produce a concrete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Eat all of the jellybeans because jellybeans are yummy.
There are 0 jellybeans in the bottle.